# Debugging an external HDD

Tags: hard-disk, external-hdd

I'm using an external HDD which is my old laptop's HD with 2.5 SATA enclosure. I tried to delete a partition in Windows and stopped it unknowingly. When I reinsert it, my OS including Ubuntu freezes and sets some duplicate partition link in the launcher. Windows too failed the test.

Here's the screen of `disks` utility:
[image]

The drive is 320GB HD which is taken during the freeze. I unplugged it and plugged it and here the output screen of the command `dmesg`:

[image: dmesg output screen]

As you can see the value 6** keeps incrementing. I know that the drive is corrupted. But, how can I flash it. I already took a backup of everything in this drive. Is there any way to format fully and get the drive back?

**UPDATE: When I inserted my disk the system freezes as I cannot use it further until I unplug the drive and it creates some duplicate copies of the two partitions I had in the disk(68 and 55GB). And even one partition I named as Misc is also shown below:**

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Start by disabling automount with:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.media-handling automount false
```

You can re-enable it when you finish changing `false` to `true`.

## Option 1 - Gparted

Install `gparted` with `sudo apt-get install gparted` or use Software Center.

Then in gparted select the correct disk and choose "Create partition table" from the Device menu. You'll have a fresh partition table. Then create partitions as needed.

## Option 2 - Disks

If gparted doesn't see the disk but "Disks" does, in the latter click the cog button and choose "Format".

## Option 3 - Fdisk

If even that fails, try `fdisk` from the command line:

1. Identify the disk with `sudo fdisk -l`. Let us say your disk is `/dev/sdb`
2. Type `sudo fdisk /dev/sdb` change the disk name appropriately
3. Choose the `w` option - Write partition table

Comment: I tried that already, the disk is not shown in the disk selection.

Comment: See modified answer.

Comment: I tried to do that, but it freezes the entire Operating System and cannot proceed further. Are there any other ways like formatting through CLI?

Comment: I added the cli manner of writing partition tables.

Comment: Thanks for your help but, whenever I try to insert the disk, duplicates are created. Please see my updated question. Even I'm able to see this after ejecting the HD.

Comment: What happens if you use a live GNU/Linux that doesn't auto-mount the drive (You can probably still use Ubuntu, I'm just not sure how to turn that normally useful feature off), what does such a system find? I suggest non-auto-mounting in case that is what is glitching up (caused by bad disk info the HDD is self-reporting). What was the filesystem format before attempting to wipe it? What does gparted / fdisk think the hdd is formated as?

Comment: @ConfusedStack Actually before I tried to wipe it off, it contained 5 partitions: one system reserved, two NTFS, two ext4.

Comment: @ConfusedStack Can I try some clean distro like Arch to do that? Or any others with automount disabled?

Comment: You can disable automount with `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.media-handling automount false` or `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.media-handling automount-open false`